# Non-abelian group $G$ satisfying $(a \cdot b)^i=a^i \cdot b^i,$ for two consecutive integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning

> Given an example of a non-abelian group $G$ satisfying $(a \cdot b)^i=a^i \cdot b^i, \forall a, b \in G$ for two consecutive integers.

This is question 5 from Herstein Page 35. I have proved that conclusion holds for three positive integers.Thanks.

Comment: If $(ab)^i=a^i b^i$ and $(ab)^{i+1}=a^{i+1}b^{i+1}$, then $ab=b^{-i}ab^{i+1}$, and so $ab^i=b^ia$.  Therefore, every $i$th power must be in the center of the group.  If you are trying to construct a group with this property, it will be easiest to assume that $a^i=e$ for every $a$.

Comment: Take the consecutive integers to be $i=0$ and $i=1$.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually possible for any finite nonabelian group. To see this, suppose $G$ is a finite nonabelian group with $|G|=n$. Then the order of any element divides $n$, hence for any element $x\in G$ we have $x^n=e$. Thus for $a,b\in G$ we have $(ab)^n=a^nb^n=e$. Furthermore, $a^{n+1}=a$, $b^{n+1}=b$, $(ab)^{n+1}=ab=a^{n+1}b^{n+1}$.

Comment: Order of every element divides order of group ? How ? and how come u have written $x^{n}$=e