# Property relationg to non-ableian group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

1. If $G$ is a group in which $(a\cdot b)^i=a^i\cdot b^i$ for three consecutive integers $i$ for all $a,b\in G$, show that $G$ is abelian.
2. Show that the conclusion of above problem does not follow if we assume the relation $(a\cdot b)^i=a^i\cdot b^i$ for just two consecutive integers.

I have solved the first spending about 3-4 hours. However, I cannot come up with the example to problem 2.

Can anyone please help with that?

Comment: Another duplicate is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199479/non-abelian-group-g-satisfying-a-cdot-bi-ai-cdot-bi-for-two-consecut?rq=1) - at the right margin there are the answers (could have saved you the 3-4 hours:)) - for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40996/prove-that-if-abi-aibi-forall-a-b-in-g-for-three-consecutive-integers?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

There are non-commutative groups of exponent $3$, for instance the Heisenberg group of order $27$. In such a group $a^3=e$ and $a^4=a$
for all $a$.

Comment: What does mean non-commutative group of exponent 3? I have never met the word "exponent" in Herstein's book.

Comment: @RFZ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228513/what-is-the-exponent-of-a-group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_group